# Is double ok for geo-coordinates in Java?

Tags: geolocation, double

Hi i want to work with geocoordinates in java.

I've defined my Java variables as "double" and my Postgres Database is defined as "double precision".

I've heared of problems with float that 0.1 results sometimes in 0.09999...

It will have to store values like 50.081406 or 8.24481.
The values will be read from an Android-Device.

Do i have to worry about floating-point problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue with the floats is usually related to addition and subtraction where due to 2's compliment (how they are stored on the computer) they don't always round out exactly to what you want.  That being said Doubles are a great way to store lat/lon

Also see: [proper/best type for storing latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385132/proper-best-type-for-storing-latitude-and-longitude)

Comment: so just for storing them, double should be ok?

Comment: Totally!  I do it all the time.  I tend to prefer doubles over floats in general now a days as memory issues are pretty negligible