# How to send a constrained double value over a network efficiently

Tags: c#, performance, networking, precision

I'm quite new to network programing.

I need to send a latitude longitude pair composed of doubles over a network. I am coding both ends so I can use whatever method I like.
At present. I'm converting both directly to bytes and sending the whole 16 bytes.

What I was wondering was, if it might be better to divide each by the maximum possible value (90 and 180 respectively) then multiply by Int32.MaxValue then convert to an int before sending.
Obviously this would halve the data sent but I can't work out how much precision I would loose.

Does anyone know how to calculate this?

Comment: "Obviously this would halve the data sent" - is that RELEVANT? Because unless this is a significant saving (i.e. you send thousands of those pair per hour) or you run on some very arcane bandwith - this sounds like work for no real gain. If you DO have a special use case, then this can help advising on a really good solution.

Comment: It's for a mobile game and I'm thinking there might, in some circumstances, be hundreds of pairs being passed per hour to each player. I'd like it to still work on older networks.

Comment: You might find valuable info about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/385132/5311735

Comment: Hundreds per hour is ultimately not much more than one every few seconds, which, given the cost of sending a single packet, is not going to make a single jot of difference even on a 56kbits modem. If you were sending gigabytes of it, that might move the needle

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure I thought that through. I would be sending a minimum of 1 pair per second. So yes, thousands per hour if not 10s of thousands.

Comment: @Evk Thanks for that link. My assumption was that I would need better than single precision floats to get a sub 1m accuracy but it appears that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You drop from 53 (type double/binary64 significand [Wikipedia IEEE_754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats)) to 32 (type integer) bits - a loss of 21 bits or roughly 6 decimal digits (2^21 ~= 2,000,000) of the 15-16 decimal digits that doubles represent.

What precision is required in your application?  Are your latitude and longitude coordinates in degrees?  At the equator 1 degree (of latitude or longitude) is roughly 110km so 3 significant digits gets you to a resolution of ~100km, 5 digits  ~1km, 8 digits ~1m, 10 digits (the best you can hope for with your transform) ~10cm.

This is just rule-of-thumbing by orders of magnitude to give you an idea.  If your coordinates must resolve to less than 10m you should proceed with caution.

Comment: Is this the whole story though? Because I know the range that the values will be in, isn't the loss of precision some what less?

Comment: @s1ni5t3r I have added to my answer.

Comment: I'm beginning to see that I don't need the precision that I thought I did. A double would be much more precise that I need. I think the solution may be to work with single precision floats throughout the whole application.

Comment: @s1ni5t3r 24bits -> ~3 decimal digits per 10 bits -> ~1m resolution -> which is the resolution of most consumer GPS devices.  (I wonder what type they use;-?.