# Calculate distance in meters when you know longitude and latitude in java

Tags: java, distance, latitude-longitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Working with latitude/longitude values in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120283/working-with-latitude-longitude-values-in-java)

#### Duplicate:

- [Working with latitude/longitude values in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120283/)
- [How do I calculate distance between two latitude longitude points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/)

I need to calculate the distance between two points given by two coordinates. The project I am working on is a Java-project, so Java-code will be great, but pseudo-code can also be given, then I can implement it myself :)

As you probably know, there are three ways to represent coordinates:

- Degrees:Minutes:Seconds (49°30'00"N, 123°30'00"W)
- Degrees:Decimal Minutes (49°30.0', -123°30.0'), (49d30.0m,-123d30.0')
- Decimal Degrees (49.5000°,-123.5000°), generally with 4-6 decimal numbers.

It's the third way my coordinates are given in, so the code for this values will be preferred :)

Comment: Take a look at <a href="http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/~cvm/latlongdist.html">this latitude/longitude distance calculator</a>. It has a link to relevant source code (including an explanation) and a link to the math behind the calculation. It's actually pretty interesting.

Comment: [This site](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) shows you the formula which is the part I assume you are having trouble with? You might want to specify if you want a straight line from point A to point B (through Earth) or if you want the distance as presented on the site. I'm sorry I don't exactly recall their names. However, the code seems relatively straightforward.

Comment: I used the code from this site successfully: * [Longditude and latitude calculation](http://www.zipcodeworld.com/samples/distance.java.html) I had to make some calculations on the answers to make it into european meters, but that was pretty straight forward :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Comment: Take a look at [GeoTools](http://geotools.codehaus.org/)' `org.geotools.referencing.GeodeticCalculator`. Set the starting and ending position then get call [`getOrthodromicDistance()`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/GeodeticCalculator.html#getOrthodromicDistance%28%29) which returns the orthodromic (great circle) distance.

Comment: If you understand mathematical formulas then this page should be more than enough to calculate distance between two points in any programming language.
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance)

Comment: Just out of curiosity. As the earth isnt a perfect sphere, (equatorial radius of 6,378.137 km and a polar radius of 6,356.752 km.)  How large would the error be?

3958.75 miles in the answer below isan approximation using the volumetric radius

Comment: See the Vicenty formula -- http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html -- if you care about the Earth not quite being a sphere

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Based on [another question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120283/), I got this code.. This calculates the result in meters, not in miles :)

```
 public static float distFrom(float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2) {
    double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
               Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
               Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);

    return dist;
    }
```

Comment: Why convert to Float and then back to float?

Comment: `return (float) (dist * meterConversion)`

Comment: The earth radius is 3958.75 in *miles* not kilometers. So your code above returns miles.

Comment: @swinefeaster: There's meterConversion constant in the second to last line which turns miles into meters.

Comment: The earth is not a perfect sphere, so this solution results in a slight error.

Comment: Just use 6369 as the earthRadius rather than Miles and then convert them to metric afterwards.

Comment: Well, it does not really matter but the earth radius is around **6371 km** not 6369 km :)

Comment: i am getting float value like this "1.2720568E-4",here i cant split the first tow decimal values..what to do?

Comment: @KarthickM Are you trying to output the float? That's what happens when you cast a float to a string. Read this for outputing floats and doubles. [stackoverflow.com/questions/15322437](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322437)

Comment: Just to be precise... this returns values in **KILOMETERS**, not in **METERS**

Comment: Earth Radius is correct. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius

Comment: Can "a" ever be negative?

Comment: using the coordinate -20.440263, -54.596051 I got a error because "a" is negative.

Comment: Why don't you use doubles (input coordinates and output distanceInKm)? Would make the code a bit cleaner/smaller ... Just wondering if there is a reason which I don't see.

Comment: @EricDarchis Is it route distance or Air Distance?

Comment: I answered with kotlin version of Haversine formula here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57346001/5788341

Comment: hey so I can use this as a geofence right???? The geofence code on android is not working for me for some unknown reason and I was thinking to use this as an alternative

Answer (score 27):

You can use the [Java Geodesy Library for GPS](http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/free-source-code/geodesy-library-vincentys-formula-java/), it uses the [Vincenty's formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) which takes account of the earths surface curvature.

Implementation goes like this:

```
import org.gavaghan.geodesy.*;

...

GeodeticCalculator geoCalc = new GeodeticCalculator();

Ellipsoid reference = Ellipsoid.WGS84;  

GlobalPosition pointA = new GlobalPosition(latitude, longitude, 0.0); // Point A

GlobalPosition userPos = new GlobalPosition(userLat, userLon, 0.0); // Point B

double distance = geoCalc.calculateGeodeticCurve(reference, userPos, pointA).getEllipsoidalDistance(); // Distance between Point A and Point B
```

The resulting distance is in meters.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ it is done like this:

```
#define LOCAL_PI 3.1415926535897932385 

double ToRadians(double degrees) 
{
  double radians = degrees * LOCAL_PI / 180;
  return radians;
}

double DirectDistance(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) 
{
  double earthRadius = 3958.75;
  double dLat = ToRadians(lat2-lat1);
  double dLng = ToRadians(lng2-lng1);
  double a = sin(dLat/2) * sin(dLat/2) + 
             cos(ToRadians(lat1)) * cos(ToRadians(lat2)) * 
             sin(dLng/2) * sin(dLng/2);
  double c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
  double dist = earthRadius * c;
  double meterConversion = 1609.00;
  return dist * meterConversion;
}
```

Comment: Can "a" ever be negative?

Comment: @XiWei No.  Latitudes are between -pi/2 and pi/2 so their cosines are positives.  And the other factors are squared.