# Can't find distance between two points

Tags: java, android, location

I have one problem about location, my program saves app's location into firebase database, it's ok, I need to compare my location with the locations in database, I used userData object to save coordinates into it:

```
Location dbLocation = new Location("dbLocation");
dbLocation.setLatitude(userData.lat);
dbLocation.setLongitude(userData.lng);
```

and I get my location coordinates from GPSTracker service:

```
Location crntLocation = new Location("crntLocation");
crntLocation.setLongitude(gpstracker.getLongitude());
crntLocation.setLatitude(gpstracker.getLatitude());
```

I need to compare this coordinates and find distance between 2 locations

```
float distanceBetween = crntLocation.distanceTo(dbLocation);
```

but it doesn't work, I don't know why, please can you help fix it?

Comment: What value do u get in `distanceBetween` ?

Comment: Have you tried `distanceBetween` method? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android distance between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534323/android-distance-between-two-points)

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?  Does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting location that is current lat,lon, you just can check the distance from origin points (lat,Lon)

```
float[] results = new float[1];
 Location.distanceBetween(currentlatitude, currentlongitude, originLat, originLon, results);
float distanceInMeters = results[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
public static double distance(Location start, Location end) {
    try {
        double distance = start.distanceTo(end);
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
        DecimalFormatSymbols custom = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        custom.setDecimalSeparator('.');
        decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(custom);
        double distanceFormated = 
        Double.parseDouble(decimalFormat.format(distance));
        return distanceFormated;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```