# Remove scientific notation on Float string with lots of trailing 0's

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to convert a HEX string into float from a data that comes from a device:

The device output in the LCD display,

`0x00ac` and the corresponding float value is `5.06`

The method that calculated the value is:

```
final byte[] temp = new byte[1];
temp[0] = ba[0];
float fff = hexToFloat(bytesToHex(temp)).floatValue();
final float ff = ( fff / 42) * 1000;
String floatString = Float.toString(ff);
```

However the floatString output string contains "E-" notation. I need to remove this. Also it seems that the value of ff is slightly different from what the device output in the LCD.

Comment: How is `0x00ac` the float `5.06`?

Comment: So you are converting a byte value to hexadecimals, just to convert it to floating points, and the question is not about the value but about the floating point representation as a `String`?

Comment: Are you sure you do not mean "leading zero's" for the title?

Comment: @owlstead Don't be sarcastic i'm just trying to ask something

Comment: @owlstead ok i accepted the question, was able to fix it by simple substring() method. haha

Comment: @xybrek so you accepted the answer although you basically used the accepted solution of the question which I've marked as a dupe. Well, good for you, hardihar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how `0x00ac` can be equal to 5.06, but here is how to get rid of the scientific notation with BigDecimals:

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(fltInput);
String numWithNoExponents = num.toPlainString()
```

Comment: FOr example, "5.605E-42" I just need to remove the "E-42", if I do BigDecimal convertion, the value would be 0.00...5605 (with lots of 0's)

Comment: I mean like "5.6054-42" need to make it "5.605" or "5.60"

Comment: `E-42` seems to me like a very important part of your floating point value... And `5.60` is not the same as `5.06` in your question.

Comment: Yes I know its important, but I just need to remove it for display