# how to find distance from polyline in android?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

How to find distance from polyline in google map in android using map apiV2 ? I want to find distance when user start moving from one location to another .
I used the [Calculate distance in meters when you know longitude and latitude in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837872/calculate-distance-in-meters-when-you-know-longitude-and-latitude-in-java) but it takes distance between two lat-long not as per user 
moves in map. Please help me if anyone knows how to find distance using polyline.

Comment: Post code you have tried already.

Answer (score 3):

For finding distance from your polyline you  can use PolyUtil class which contains one method distanceToLine .
 implementation'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
add this library in your build.gradle.
For more you can use Google map utility class

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use thread. In that at regular interval you should find the distance between current coordinates and last saved coordinate.

Raw code:

```
Coordinate current, last;
Distance D = 0;

while (true) {
  wait(10000);
  last = current;
  current = getNewCordinate;
  d = D + distFrom(current, last);
}
```

This logic will help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer given by [Gevaria Purva](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37937476/245495) I found a more appropriate method on PolyUtil named [isLocationOnPath](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnPath-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-double-).
For the third parameter most likely you want to pass `true`.