# Test Data for Geo Location Search using MongoDB and Spring Data

Tags: spring, mongodb, geolocation, spring-data, latitude-longitude

I am trying to implement Geo Location search using Mongo DB and Spring Data.

I set up MongoDB correctly and enabled geo location index

```
db.track.ensureIndex( { start : "2d" } );
```

I created the following services :

1. Search nearby from DB `:http://localhost:8080/secure/track/get/11.53144/48.15672/0.5`
2. Add Location to DB `http://localhost/secure/track/add`

The values are getting added properly as i can see them in the DB.

My question is what test data should i use to test if i am getting list of objects nearby to a location.Since i am not well versed with latitude/longitude ,this will be of great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very clear for me: are you looking for a way to determine if the order of the POI returned is good? If it is the case:

There is a formula that will give you the distance between 2 points from their latitude/longitude.

I found in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837872/calculate-distance-in-meters-when-you-know-longitude-and-latitude-in-java):

```
public static float distFrom(float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2) {
    double earthRadius = 6371; //kilometers
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
           Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
           Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);
    return dist;
}
```

Then the best thing to do is to insert a batch of data that you know to be near your point of interest and check that the order is good.

I hope that answers your question.. Else, do not hesitate to edit or comment!

Comment: Yes this would help me , I was actually looking for set of points itself, but this should be good