# A Way To Get Most Accurate Distance in Meters Android

Tags: android, distance, measurement

I'm trying to develop an application which going to calculate the most possible accurate distance between position where device is located at first, and final position of the device after user moved by bicycle. The value should be in meters.

I was able to do this using GPS before, using method which get device's coordinate every 10 seconds, then calculate distance in meters, and get the distance this way ((1st coordinate + 2nd coordinate) + (2st coordinate + 3nd coordinate) + (3st coordinate + 4nd coordinate) and so on).

But there are some issues where android GPS is said that could have some innacuracy until several meters. There also delay when I stop at some point, the coordinate keep changing and thus, the distance's keep increasing about 10 - 20 meters until it stopped at about 20 seconds to minutes. The coordinate and distance are supposed to stop or if they aren't, should increasing only a little when I stopped.

The application is supposed to be precise and on time about the result, so I don't think I'm should use the GPS.

I also read that motion sensors, accelerometer in android is no good for this purpose. So, is there a way for me to achieve my purpose above? Is there any paid plugin or method so I can achieve my purpose? Thank You.

Comment: try google play services -- http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/  -- and some math to calculate distance -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837872/calculate-distance-in-meters-when-you-know-longitude-and-latitude-in-java

Comment: google play services still based on GPS or network provider, therefore it wouldn't be more accurate than my previous code. Anyway thank you for your response.

Comment: Phones don't have Survey Grade GPS built into them yet so if you want an accuracy of within 1 centimeter horizontally and 2 centimeters vertically you have to wait a few years till that technology is available in a smartphone. for the moment you have to do with what the phones ability is. There are several third party external GPS receivers that connect to the smart phone via Bluetooth and will provide < 3 meter accuracy -- http://www.fulcrumapp.com/blog/bluetooth-gps-comparison/

Comment: So it does impossible then. Okay, thank you again.