# Run a geospatial query in memory using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, geometry, geospatial

Is there a way to run in Scala a geospatial query, given a set of lat/lon coordinates, to find nearest by distance? The query needs to run in memory possibly.

The set of values is roughly 1 million lon/lat coordinates. I am trying to do that in Spark but the only solution I have found is [Magellan](https://github.com/harsha2010/magellan) but I cannot make it even work for Spark 1.6 and Scala 2.11 so I am trying  customized solution.

Example of query: Given one point in wgs84 coordinates and the 1 million set of wsg84 coords, I want the nearest 15 coords in a radius of one mile.

Comment: Could you please give us some details? Are you using a database or any other data store? How is the coordinates stored? How big is your dataset?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: What problem are you having with Magellan? How did you try to use it? Any error messages?

Comment: I am trying just to put it in my sbt file as normal dependency and it cannot be found in any repository and it looks it has only scala version 2.10 available

Comment: See if this blog post helps you: http://hortonworks.com/blog/magellan-geospatial-analytics-in-spark/

Comment: Magellan also doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a library with RTree implemetation that can be used for indexing of geo data in Scala: https://github.com/davidmoten/rtree

Just select by bounding box rectangle(s) for your point which will be center of a circle with given radius (distance in your case) and then filter points by the distance to cut out false positives in corners of  bounding boxes and then sort results by already calculated distance to take required the nearest 15.

You can use the ‘haversine’ formula to check distance condition between points (see description here http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html):

```
import java.lang.Math._
import com.github.davidmoten.rtree.geometry.{Point, Rectangle}
import com.github.davidmoten.rtree.geometry.Geometries._

def distance(p1: Point, p2: Point): Double = {
  val radLon1 = toRadians(p1.x)
  val radLat1 = toRadians(p1.y)
  val radLon2 = toRadians(p2.x)
  val radLat2 = toRadians(p2.y)
  val x = sin((radLon2 - radLon1) * 0.5)
  val y = sin((radLat2 - radLat1) * 0.5)
  val a = y * y + cos(radLat1) * cos(radLat2) * x * x
  atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a)) * 12756274 // The Earth diameter in meters
}
```

For calculation of bounding boxes use following function:

```
def boundingRectangles(c: Point, r: Double): List[Rectangle] = {
  val radLon = toRadians(c.x)
  val radLat = toRadians(c.y)
  val radDist = r / 6378137 // The Earth radius in meters
  val lat1 = toDegrees(radLat - radDist)
  val lat2 = toDegrees(radLat + radDist)
  if (lat1 > -90 && lat2 < 90) {
    val deltaLon = asin(sin(radDist) / cos(radLat))
    val lon1 = toDegrees(radLon - deltaLon)
    val lon2 = toDegrees(radLon + deltaLon)
    if (lon1 < -180) rectangle(-180, lat1, lon2, lat2) :: rectangle(lon1 + 360, lat1, 180, lat2) :: Nil
    else if (lon2 > 180) rectangle(-180, lat1, lon2 - 360, lat2) :: rectangle(lon1, lat1, 180, lat2) :: Nil
    else rectangle(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) :: Nil
  } else rectangle(-180, max(lat1, -90), 180, min(lat2, 90)) :: Nil
}
```

List of rectangles required for case when a circle is crossed by the date change meridian, because the RTree doesn't support wrapping of geo-coordinates over the Earth, so we split that rectangles on two by the date change meridian.

Formula and description are here http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates#Longitude

EDIT: Finally we ended up to have our own version of the immutable RTree with STR packing that is tuned for efficient window and knn queries on both plane and spherical geometries:

https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/rtree2d

Comment: Thank you, very interesting answer! Is there a way to build geohash/2d-sphere indexes in memory too?

Answer (score 0):

if you want arbitrary datums then you probably need a library but if it is just distance in wgs84 it is a straight forward formula see for example the response to [Calculate distance in meters when you know longitude and latitude in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837872/calculate-distance-in-meters-when-you-know-longitude-and-latitude-in-java)