# How to Check Geocode included in a Range of Place?

Tags: php, maps, geocoding, here-api

I am developing web application that deals with a shopping cart.
Including customer registration and store registration.

When registering a store we are collecting the latitude and longitude of the store position. 
Once the store releasing any notifications, first needs to check the Customer addresses having 1 KM radius of the store position.

Only the satisfied customers want the notification.

I am collecting the Latitudes and longitudes of 1 KM range with Here Map API.

[Here Map Isoline API](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/request-isoline.html)

The response of the above API is a bunch of Latitudes and Longitudes.

How can I check my Store latitude and longitude is in this range of Geo-codes.

I tried **in_array** function of PHP and not accurate with that.
Is there any other solution for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Already you are saving the store's latitude and longitude. You can get the latitude and longitude of customer address.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Then calculate the distance between the latitude and longitude using the method.
[Calculate distance in meters when you know longitude and latitude in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837872/calculate-distance-in-meters-when-you-know-longitude-and-latitude-in-java)

If the distance is less than 1km, then execute push notification script for that customer.