# How can i get the distance between the two longitude and two latitude in kilometer in android?

Tags: android, json

Explanation:
            I know this question is mostly repeated but i have some bit of confusion. I am working on live application. In which, i read the JSON data in json there is some longitude and latitude are there. I fetch the compare with the current longitude and latitude. I found some methods and i tried but not got the expected output.

I want to compare when my current longitude and latitude is under the five kilemeters(km) from the json latitude and longitude. If the user is out of the range like more then a the five kilometer it's show the message user out of range.

Here, is my code to get the longtitude and latitude

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener{

    public static final String TAG=TransactionFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String KEY_UGC="postData[ugc]";
    public static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_ID="postData[customerid]";
    public static final String KEY_UGC_ID="postData[ugcid]";

    View rootView;
    PreferenceSetting prefManager;

    ListView lvTransaction;
    List<String> items;
    TextView txtPoints;
    Button btnUgc,btnMore;
    List<Trasaction> trasactionList;
    TextView lblTrasaction,lblStation,lblNoBottle,lblPointsColl,lblPoints;

    int totalPoints=0;
    MainActivity activity;

    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private double currentLatitude;
    private double currentLongitude;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

        prefManager=PreferenceSetting.getInstance(getActivity());


        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                // The next two lines tell the new client that “this” current class will handle connection stuff
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                //fourth line adds the LocationServices API endpoint from GooglePlayServices
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

        activity=(MainActivity)getActivity();
        lblTrasaction=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_trasaction);
        lblTrasaction.setTypeface(AppController.fntAlice);

        lblStation=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_station);
        lblStation.setTypeface(AppController.fntVani);

        lblNoBottle=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_no_bottle);
        lblNoBottle.setTypeface(AppController.fntVani);

        lblPointsColl=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_points_coll);
        lblPointsColl.setTypeface(AppController.fntVani);

        lblPoints=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_points);
        lblPoints.setTypeface(AppController.fntVani);

        btnUgc=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_ugc);
        btnUgc.setTypeface(AppController.fntVani);

        btnMore=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_more);
        btnMore.setTypeface(AppController.fntVani);

        txtPoints=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_points);
        txtPoints.setTypeface(AppController.fntVani);

        if(prefManager.getPoints()==0){
            txtPoints.setText("0");
        }
        else{
            txtPoints.setText(""+prefManager.getPoints());
        }
        if(Utils.isNetworkConnected(getActivity())){
            RequestParams params=new RequestParams();
            params.put(ApiCalls.REQUEST_CASE_LABEL,"customerHistory");
            params.put("postData[customerid]",prefManager.getCustomerId());
            getTransactionApiCall(params);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getString(R.string.internet), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        items=new ArrayList<>();

        lvTransaction=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_transaction);

        btnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Message message=new Message();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("more","1");
                message.setData(bundle);
                activity.uiHandler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        });
        btnUgc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onPause()");

        //Disconnect from API onPause()
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return  ;
        }
        else {
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

            if (location == null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

            } else {
                currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Error", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    public void getUcgCallApi(final RequestParams params){
        AsyncHttpClient client=new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.setTimeout(AsyncHttpClient.DEFAULT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
        client.post(ApiCalls.API_CALL, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                Log.i(TAG,"GET UGC PARAMS:->>>"+params.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                try{
                    String str=new String(responseBody);
                    JSONObject mainObj=new JSONObject(str);
                    Log.e(TAG,"SUCCESS RESPONSE:=>>"+mainObj.toString());

                    if(mainObj.has("status") && !mainObj.isNull("status")){
                        if(mainObj.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
                            JSONArray data=mainObj.getJSONArray("data");

                            JSONObject dataObj=data.getJSONObject(0);

                            prefManager.setPkUgcId(dataObj.getString("PK_UGC_ID"));
                            prefManager.setUgcCode(dataObj.getString("UGC_CODE"));

                            if(!prefManager.getPkUgcId().equals(PreferenceSetting.DEFAULT)){
                                Log.e(TAG,"UGC ID STORED::"+prefManager.getPkUgcId()+"\nUGC CODE::->"+prefManager.getUgcCode());

                                Date timeDate=Utils.getDate(Long.parseLong(dataObj.getString("EXPIRED_TIME")));

                                Log.e(TAG,"DATE UTIL:->"+timeDate);
                                Date currentDate=new Date();

                                double LOCATION_LATITUDE=Double.parseDouble(dataObj.getString("LOCATION_LATITUDE"));
                                double LOCATION_LONGITUDE=Double.parseDouble(dataObj.getString("LOCATION_LONGITUDE"));

                                Log.e(TAG,"GETCURRENT TIME:->"+currentDate.toString());

                                if(timeDate.after(currentDate)){
                                    Log.e(TAG,"FIRST DISTANCE:->"+distance(currentLatitude,currentLongitude,LOCATION_LATITUDE,LOCATION_LONGITUDE));
                                    if((distance(currentLatitude,currentLongitude,LOCATION_LATITUDE,LOCATION_LONGITUDE)/1000) <= 5 ) {
                                        Log.e(TAG,"AFTER DISTANCE:->"+distance(currentLatitude,currentLongitude,LOCATION_LATITUDE,LOCATION_LONGITUDE));
                                        RequestParams reqParams = new RequestParams();
                                        reqParams.put(ApiCalls.REQUEST_CASE_LABEL, "UGCReading");
                                        reqParams.put(KEY_UGC, prefManager.getUgcCode());
                                        reqParams.put(KEY_CUSTOMER_ID, prefManager.getCustomerId());
                                        reqParams.put(KEY_UGC_ID, prefManager.getPkUgcId());
//                                        readUgcCodeApiCall(reqParams);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "“You are out of range for redeem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                                if(timeDate.before(currentDate)){
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "UGC Code Expired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), mainObj.getString("status"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e(TAG,"on Success()==>"+Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                try{
                    String str=new String(responseBody);
                    JSONObject mainObj=new JSONObject(str);

                    Log.e(TAG,"FAILURE RESPONSE:=>>"+mainObj.toString());
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e(TAG,"on Failure()==>"+Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void readUgcCodeApiCall(final RequestParams params){
        AsyncHttpClient client=new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.setTimeout(AsyncHttpClient.DEFAULT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
        client.post(ApiCalls.API_CALL, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                Log.e(TAG,"PARAMS:->>>"+params.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                try {
                    String str=new String(responseBody);
                    JSONObject mainObj=new JSONObject(str);
                    Log.e(TAG,"SUCCESS RESPONSE readUgcCodeApiCall :=>>"+mainObj.toString());

                    if(mainObj.has("status") && !mainObj.isNull("status")){
                        if(mainObj.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getString(R.string.success), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            RequestParams params=new RequestParams();
                            params.put(ApiCalls.REQUEST_CASE_LABEL,"customerHistory");
                            params.put("postData[customerid]",prefManager.getCustomerId());
                            getTransactionApiCall(params);
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getString(R.string.unsuccess), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"on Success()==>"+Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                try {
                    String str=new String(responseBody);
                    JSONObject mainObj=new JSONObject(str);
                    Log.e(TAG,"FAILURE RESPONSE:=>>"+mainObj.toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"on Failure()==>"+Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        return (dist);
    }

    private double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }
    private double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }
    public void showDialog(){

        final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(getContext());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.claim_dialog);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        final EditText editClaim=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_claim);
//        editClaim.setTypeface(AppController.fntVani);
        Button btnClaim=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_claim);
        btnClaim.setTypeface(AppController.fntVani);

        btnClaim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(!editClaim.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {

                    if (Utils.isNetworkConnected(getActivity())) {
                        RequestParams params=new RequestParams();
                        params.put(ApiCalls.REQUEST_CASE_LABEL,"getUGCDetails");
                        params.put(KEY_UGC,editClaim.getText().toString().trim());
                        getUcgCallApi(params);
                        if(dialog.isShowing()){
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.internet), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

JSON RESPONSE

[image]

In above code there is a one method namely getUcgCallApi() in this i tried to compare old and current longitude and latitude.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this for getting distance between two lat - long :

```
float[] distance = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(mLocation.latitude, mLocation.longitude, locations.latitude, locations.longitude, distance);
```

The computed distance is stored in `distance[0]`. If distance has length 2 or greater, the initial bearing is stored in `distance[1]`. If distance has length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in `distance[2]`.

Comment: What i need to pass in distance parameter of this method?

Comment: the float values is in the meter or kilometer?

Comment: it is in kilometer

Answer (score 0):

check this link it will be helpful to you:

[Calculate distance in meters when you know longitude and latitude in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837872/calculate-distance-in-meters-when-you-know-longitude-and-latitude-in-java)

```
public static float distFrom(float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2) {
    double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
               Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
               Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);

    return dist;
    }
```

Call this method:

```
float meter= distFrom(LOCATION_LATITUDE1,LOCATION_LONGITUDE2,LOCATION_LATITUDE2,LOCATION_LONGITUDE2);


final float kilometer=meter/1000;
```

you can convert meter distance to kilometer.