# Find distance between two points (lat/long) in sparkdataframe in pypspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, distance, latitude-longitude

How can I compute the distance below spark dataframe between Location A and B and Location A and Location C?

```
  spark = SparkSession(sc)
  df = spark.createDataFrame([('A', 
  40.202750,29.168350,'B',40.689247,-74.044502),('A', 
  40.202750,29.168350,'C',25.197197,55.274376)], ['Location1', 'Lat1', 
  'Long1', 'Location2', 'Lat2', 'Lon2'])
```

So the dataset below:

```
    +---------+--------+--------+---------+---------+----------+
    |Location1|    Lat1|   Long1|Location2|     Lat2|      Lon2|
    +---------+--------+--------+---------+---------+----------+
    |        A|40.20275|29.16835|        B|40.689247|-74.044502|
    |        A|40.20275|29.16835|        C|25.197197| 55.274376|
    +---------+--------+--------+---------+---------+----------+
```

Thank you

Comment: You could use something like `val df1 = df.withColumn("distance", distance(df("Lat1"), df("Long1"), df("Lat2"), df("Long2")))` - you will need to write the function to work out the distance (eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837872/calculate-distance-in-meters-when-you-know-longitude-and-latitude-in-java)

Comment: Maybe something like https://datasystemslab.github.io/GeoSpark/ could help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) which goes something like

```
2*6378*asin(sqrt(pow(sin((lat2-lat1)/2),2) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*pow(sin((lon2-lon1)/2),2)))
```

Furthermore, you can create a UDF for the same which would be

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
  return 2*6378*sqrt(pow(sin((lat2-lat1)/2),2) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*pow(sin((lon2-lon1)/2),2))

dist_udf=F.udf(haversine, FloatType())
```

**Make sure your latitude and longitude values are in radians.**

You could add that conversion as part of the `haversine` function before the calculation part

Once you have the UDF, you can straightaway do

```
df.withColumn('distance', dist_udf(F.col('lat1'), F.col('long1'), F.col('lat2'), F.col('long2')))
```