# Calculate square around a lat/long

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to calc a square around a single point but I keep getting a rectangle.

This is the point -80.42816162109375, 26.686729520004036.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

```
int lat_feet = long_feet = 50;
double lat_meters = lat_feet * .3048;
double long_meters = long_feet * .3048;
var earth = 6378137;

var l1 = lat + (180 / Math.PI) * (lat_meters / earth);
var l2 = llong + (180 / Math.PI) * (long_meters / earth) / Math.Cos(lat);
```

Comment: Longitudes aren't constant, they vary with latitude. At the equator you'd get a square.

Comment: Is there a reliable way to calc a square?

Comment: You could start by checking out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024404/transform-longitude-latitude-into-meters.

Comment: Using dividing by `Math.Cos(lat)` is right, and you should get rather good square approximation **at the map**. Is there some mistake like degree argument of Cos or something else? How do you see rectangle? For what data?

Comment: Please specify what you want. There is no square in the usual sense on a sphere. Do you want a square in a projection of the sphere / map? Then, what projection do you use?

Comment: I added an image of what it looks like along with the lat/long

Comment: Show result values

Comment: Thanks for adding code. You don't mention a language, but pretty much all of them require radians as input to `Cos` but you're supplying degrees.