# Java: questions about radians, Math.cos, Math.sin, double and long

Tags: java, math

I need to implement the harvesine distance in my java code.

I found this snippet in Javascript, and I need to convert it to java.

1. How can I convert latitude and longitude to radians in Java ?
2. Math.sin wants a double in Java. Should I pass the previously converted value in radians or not ?
3. Math.sin and Math.cos return long. Should I declare a as long and pass it to Math.sqrt or convert it to double ?

thanks

```
dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
dLon = (lng2-lng1).toRad(); 
a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
d = R * c;
return d;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution here:

[How can I measure distance and create a bounding box based on two latitude+longitude points in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120283/working-with-latitude-longitude-values-in-java)

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you should read the javadoc. [sin(double)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin(double)) takes a `double` in parameter which is the angle in radians like said in the documentation. You'll also find on the linked page that sqrt takes a double as well.

Then, you should know that java can perform non-destructive conversion automatically. So if a method takes a double and you have a long, it will be no problem, since there's no loss in the conversion long -> double. The reverse is false, so Java refuse ton compile.

For the radians conversion, you'll find a [toRadians](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians(double)) method in the Math class.

Comment: There can be a loss in the conversion long->double. For example, if the long value is an odd number above 2^53 (or below -2^53), it can't be represented exactly as a double value. For some reason, the JLS elects to ignore these conversion losses, though, and treats this conversion as a widening conversion. (Same problem for int->float and long->float - here the limit is 2^24.)

Comment: Patrick never reads the documentation for anything, instead he asks here on SO.

Answer (score 5):

1. If you have value in degrees, just do `degrees * Math.PI / 180`. Or better use function suggested by **coobird** in the comment (didn't know of it).
2. Yes, you can pass any double value in it. (Any number, for that matter.)
3. No, both functions take `double` parameter. Check [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos%28double%29).

Comment: For (1), using `Math.toRadians(degrees)` would be easier to read.