# How to compute the lat/lon from EPSG land cover system?

Tags: latitude-longitude, wgs84, epsg

I have a polygon in land cover with 4 coordinates (north-south, east-west) and I would like to compute the latitude and longitude.
For example, Bounding Box: `West = -10.61982, East = 44.82124, North = 71.18545, South = 34.56192`
Does anybody know the basic steps?
It seems that is the inverse of the following problem:
[How to translate a given coordinate into a bounding box of "diameter" x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459247/how-to-translate-a-given-coordinate-into-a-bounding-box-of-diameter-x)
Thank you!