# How to compute the bounding box of the given set of coordinates on the map

Tags: java, gis, bounding-box

I have a set (2 or more) of coordinates with a given  Latitude and Longitude. How to compute the Upper Left Corner and Lower Down Corner of a bounding box on the map in Java

Comment: Can you post your solution if you found it?

Answer (score 0):

You could cheat and use [Rectangle2D.Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html). You can [Point2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html) objects to it.  This give you the upper limit (x+width/y+height) and lower limit (x/y)

When all you have is a hammer, all your problems look like nails - sorry if this is quite what your looking for, it's just what came to mind

Comment: This solution doesn't take into account that we are working with sphere  ( the Earth) not with a plane.

Comment: Point, try having a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120283/working-with-latitude-longitude-values-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238260/how-to-calculate-the-bounding-box-for-a-given-lat-lng-location and http://geokit.rubyforge.org/api/geokit-gem/index.html while, strickly not all in Java that should provide you some jumping off points