# Open source library for reading latitude and longitude from JPEG / EXIF in Java?

Tags: java, gps, latitude-longitude, exif

I want to extract the latitude and longitude from the EXIF information in jpeg images. I am looking for a Java-based open source library.

Comment: Longitude and latitude, IF they exist in a jpeg, are in the EXIF headers. Just google around for how to read jpeg EXIF headers in Java.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120283/working-with-latitude-longitude-values-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used it myself, but I have been told good thinks about this:

http://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a library to read jpeg geotag data.  I looked at Metadata Extractor written by Drew Noakes, as suggested by mjshaw.  However it had way more than I needed.  So I created a slimmed down version available here: https://github.com/alecdhuse/Java-Jpeg-Geotag-Reader

It will return latitude, longitude, altitude and the time from the photo's exif data.