# Laravel Eloquent - Fetch results based on lat/lon radius

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, geospatial

I have a `Model` called `Place` having a simple structure:

```
| id | name  | lat       | lon         | 
|----|-------|-----------|-------------|
| 1  | hotel | 33.755787 | -116.359998 |
| 2  | shop  | 44.968046 | -94.420307  |
| 3  | park  | 44.333304 | -91.493768  |
```

What I need is something like `Place::whereRadius(100)->get()` or some accurate latitude/longitude so that I can build a query like this:

```php
Place::whereBetween('lat',latitudes)->whereBetween('lon',longitude)->get();
```

Currently my approach is to get lat/lon points of a circle of `radius` apart from my desired lat/lon point which I did via `turf.js` on frontend and got an array of lat/lon coordinates like this:

```php
//example not real calculation
[
 [33.755787, -116.359998],
 [44.968046, -94.420307],
 [44.333304, -91.493768]
]
```

My next step was to calculate possible max and min points within the **area** of the above received circle but it's not promising accurate results with larger datasets or larger circles even in small datasets.

Is there an efficient way to query lat/lon based on radius & with some Eloquence if possible?

**Edit** I am looking for Laravel/Eloquent way of doing it. Raw MySQL based radius as suggested can technically work but isn't exactly what I asked for in the question

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372705/calculating-a-radius-with-longitude-and-latitude and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

Comment: @RyanNerd I am not asking for calculating a circle, that I can do, what I need is to fetch the points within that circle from DB

Comment: I worked this out in plain SQL, not Eloquent, here: https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/