# Combing Leaflet Maps Together

Tags: r, leaflet, data-visualization

I generated these 2 random dataset about geographical coordinates (e.g. each point represents an imaginary restaurant in France):

```
    id = 1:1000
    long = 2.2945 + rnorm( 1000, 0.1085246 , 0.1)
    lat = 48.8584 + rnorm( 1000, 0.009036273 , 0.1)
    
    my_data_1 = data.frame(id, lat, long)

id = 1:1000
    long = 2.2945 + rnorm( 1000, 0.1085246 , 0.1)
    lat = 48.8584 + rnorm( 1000, 0.009036273 , 0.1)
    

   my_data_2 = data.frame(id, lat, long)
```

I then made these 4 maps:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)


map1 = my_data_1 %>%
    leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addHeatmap(lng=~long,lat=~lat,max=100,radius=20,blur=10)


map2 = my_data_2 %>%
    leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addHeatmap(lng=~long,lat=~lat,max=100,radius=20,blur=10)


map3 = my_data_1 %>% 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(clusterOption=markerClusterOptions())

map4 = my_data_2 %>% 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(clusterOption=markerClusterOptions())
```

**I would like to combine all these 4 maps into a single map (i.e. a single html file). That is, I would like there to be a window on the right side with 4 toggle buttons :map1, map2, map3, map4. I would like that someone could click these 4 buttons and the corresponding map would load. (only one map can be loaded at a time)**

I found this link over here that shows how to combine maps (https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html) - but I do not think that this can be directly used to solve the problem I am working on. This would have been useful if I had different "classes" of restaurants (e.g. cafes, vegan restaurant, fancy restaurant, etc.) and I wanted to toggle between the different restaurants on the same map - however, I want to toggle between 4 completely different maps.

- I am wondering: is there a straightforward option within the "leaflet" library that can be used to do this? Or does a function need to be written to accomplish this?

For example: `c(map1, map2, map3, map4)`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [flexdashboard](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/articles/layouts.html) is what you are looking for leaving you with a `html` document.

Using `Rmd` file:

````
---
title: "maps"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---
    
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
#library(flexdashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
id = 1:1000
long = 2.2945 + rnorm( 1000, 0.1085246 , 0.1)
lat = 48.8584 + rnorm( 1000, 0.009036273 , 0.1)
my_data_1 = data.frame(id, lat, long)
id = 1:1000
long = 2.2945 + rnorm( 1000, 0.1085246 , 0.1)
lat = 48.8584 + rnorm( 1000, 0.009036273 , 0.1)
my_data_2 = data.frame(id, lat, long)

```    
  
   
Column {.tabset}
-------------------------------------
   
### map 1

```{r}
map1 = my_data_1 %>%
    leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addHeatmap(lng=~long,lat=~lat,max=100,radius=20,blur=10)
map1
```   
 
### map 2
    
```{r}
map2 = my_data_2 %>%
    leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addHeatmap(lng=~long,lat=~lat,max=100,radius=20,blur=10)
map2
```

### map 3
    
```{r}
map3 = my_data_1 %>% 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(clusterOption=markerClusterOptions())
map3

```

### map 4
    
```{r}
map4 = my_data_2 %>% 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(clusterOption=markerClusterOptions())
map4
```
````

[image]

Comment: @ user63230: thank you so much! This looks great! Just to clarify - I have to copy/paste your code into a R markdown page and then "knit" this to a RMD file? thank you so much!

Comment: yes, open `Rmarkdown` document, copy and paste the code and press knit

Comment: Another question - is there a way to change the name of each of the "tabs"? And is it possible to add any visualization with these tabs (e.g. mix and match bar charts and geographical maps ... by just pasting the code into these blocks? Thank you so much!

Comment: I think I will follow this example to do this: https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/jjallaire/htmlwidgets-showcase-storyboard/htmlwidgets-showcase-storyboard.html

Answer (score 3):

You could use the package `htmltools` and `shinyRPG` (this is *not* a Shiny app). Last time I looked, `shinyRPG` wasn't a Cran package, you'll have to get this from Github.

```
devtools::install_github("RinteRface/shinyRPG")
```

Leaving your code as is, I used `rpgSelect` to create the selection list and a lot of the formatting.

```
tagSel <- rpgSelect(
  "selectBox",
  "Selections:",
  c(setNames(1:4, paste0("map", 1:4))), # left is values, right is labels
  multiple = T
)
tagSel$attribs$class <- 'select'
tagSel$children[[2]]$attribs$onchange <- "getOps(this)"
```

Then I used `htmltools` to create one `htmlwidget` that contains all four graphs and a selection list (not buttons). I did add a bit of styling.

First, `browsable()` so that the JS, CSS, and R widgets are consolidated into one object. In the `tags$head` or `<head>`, I've got 2 JS scripts and one element for styles.

The first `<script>` stacks the maps on top of each other.
The second `<script>` changes the map that you see based on your selection.
The styles address the selection box (`.select`), the options (`#selectBox`), and the space allocated for the maps versus the selection list.
The `<body>` contains the four maps and the selection list.

```
browsable(tagList(list(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML("setTimeout(function(){ /* stack maps */
            $('[id^=\"htmlwidget-\"]').css({top: 0, 
                                            position:'absolute',
                                            'z-index': -10});
            $('[id^=\"htmlwidget-\"]').first().css({'z-index': 1000});
            }, 100)")),
    tags$script(HTML("function getOps(sel) { /* activate select */
            graphy = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=\"htmlwidget-\"]');
            $('[id^=\"htmlwidget-\"]').css({'z-index': -10});
            for(i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
              opt = sel.options[i];
              if ( opt.selected ) {
                console.log(opt);
                graphy[i].style.zIndex = '1000';
              } else {
                graphy[1].style.zIndex = '-10';
              }
            }
          }")),
    tags$style(".select{ 
                 position: relative; width: 13ch;
                 border: 2px solid #003b70;
                 margin: 0 2px;
                 border-radius: 5px; font-size: 1.1em;
                 text-align: center; line-height: 1.25em;
               }
               #selectBox{
                 background-color: #003b70;
                 width: 10ch; text-align: center;
                 color: white; font-weight: bold;
                 line-height: 1.25em;
               }
               .yaLeft{
                position: relative;
                float: left; width: 85%;
                height: 80ch;
               }
               .yaRight{
                 float: right; width: 15%;}")),
  div(div(class = "yaLeft",
          map1, map2, map3, map4), 
      div(class = "yaRight", tagSel)))))
```

[image]

[image]