# Java Mathematical Expression Syntax

Tags: java

I dont have experience with Java math expression. I'm trying to calulate distance between two locations using the below java expression but my application is give the below error message

```
sqrt((var1___4 - var2___4)^2 + (var1___5 - var2___5)^2)
```

Error Msg : The variable [var___5] inside the jave mathematical expression is not found.

Comment: can you include initialization of the variables?

Comment: I dont see variable var___5.

Comment: Can you show us the context of your code? You don't even use var___5.

Comment: In addition the `...^2` is not doing what you think it does.

Comment: Dude, use some decent variable names. No wonder it gives symbol not found... And ^ is XOR, not power.

Comment: Since I doubt any Java exceptions misspell "Java", can you copy/paste the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Side note: Java comes with a [Math.hypot(x, y)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot%28double,%20double%29) function, so you can do `Math.hypot(x1 - x2, y1 - y2)`. This has the benefit of not overflowing the final result in case `x*x` or `y*y` would overflow. Sadly, not enough developers are aware of this gem.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a function that will calculate distance for you:

```
public double getDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
    double dx = x1-x2;
    double dy = y1-y2;
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```

The `^` character is not a valid way to raise a number to a power in java. [Here's a link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) to valid operators in Java.

Also you must reference the static square root function, [Math.sqrt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29), to calculate the root of a number.

I recommend you use a utility function for calculations like this as they're more difficult to read than an well named function (like the one given here.)

Edit:

In comments, Ted suggested using [Math.hypot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot%28double,%20double%29) instead of Math.sqrt if you are using java 1.5 or better. The function then, would look like this:

```
public double getDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
    double dx = x1-x2;
    double dy = y1-y2;
    return Math.hypot(dx, dy);
}
```

If you are using Java 1.5 or better, this is a better solution because hypot prevents overflow or underflow in computing the square of `dx` and `dy`.

Comment: Or if using Java 1.5 or later, simply `return Math.hypot(x1-x2, y1-y2);`.

Comment: The var___5 was a typo. I'm using an application which has java mathematical expression to calculate. Consider the var1 as a database table with 5 columns, Col1 is the username and col4 is longitude and col5 is latitude. Then there is another table with the same information (Col1=username, col4=longitude, col5=latitude). I want to compare the two to calculate the distance. I found this jave math expression in the application KB.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that existed. Thanks for the knowledge Ted, I'll update my answer and credit you.

Comment: Ok, does this work for you @HarryD?

Comment: @WilliamMorrison - How do I tell it to compare col4 of table1 with col4 of table2?

Comment: For each row in the table, retrieve the cell for each of your latitutde,longitude columns, and perform the distance function I've given above. However, if this is latitude and longitude, you probably shouldn't use straightline distance, but something like the [Haversine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120283/working-with-latitude-longitude-values-in-java) formula for measuring distance on a spherical object like the earth.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how:

```
Math.sqrt(Math.pow(var1___4 - var2___4, 2) + Math.pow(var1___5 - var2___5, 2));
```

Take note:

- In Java, all mathematical functions reside in the `Math` class, as static methods
- To take the square root of a number `n`, use `Math.sqrt(n)`
- To square a number `n`, use `Math.pow(n, 2)` or simply `n * n`

Answer (score 1):

The `^` isn't the Mathematical Power Operator in Java, it is the `Bitwise exclusive OR`.

So you need to write `Math.pow(x, y)` instead.

Thereby to fix you code you need to write the following instead.

```
Math.sqrt(Math.pow(var1___4 - var2___4, 2) + Math.pow(var1___5 - var2___5, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `^` operator isn't used for exponentiation in Java. If you want to square a value, you can use the `pow` method of the `math` class:

`sqrt(Math.pow((var1___4 - var2___4),2) + Math.pow((var1___5 - var2___5),2));`

You're also missing a semi-colon at the end of your statement.

The variable `var___5` isn't used in your code sample, but if it's `not found` then you haven't declared it before using it.